# JAVA - Concurrency and locks

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I need to create a hash map like this:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>>
```

and I'm using 2 threads.

Here a sample of the output map:

```
---------------------
| xxx | a  b  c  d  |
| yyy | a' b' c' d' |
| zzz | A  B  C  D  |
---------------------
```

Both threads contribute to the creation of an entry; so, for example, thread 1 has the following data set to store:

```
-----------------------------------
| 1 |  (xxx,a)  (yyy,a')  (zzz,A) |
| 2 |  (xxx,b)  (yyy,b')  (zzz,B) |
-----------------------------------
```

and thread 2 has:

---

```
| 1 |  (xxx,c)  (yyy,c')  (zzz,C) |
| 2 |  (xxx,d)  (yyy,d')  (zzz,D) |
-----------------------------------
```

So, at the same moment, the two threads may compute the same key: thread 1 (xxx,a) and thread 2 (xxx,c).

What is the best lock/unlock mechanism I could use?

I tried the following one

```
ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

executor.submit(() -> {
   lock.writeLock().lock();
   try {
      sleep(1);
      map.put("foo", "bar");
  } finally {
     lock.writeLock().unlock();
  }
```

});

but I don't want to lock the entire hash map. I want to create a lock IF AND ONLY IF both threads during the processing should work on the same key.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should use a concurrent Map:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Second you should populate it with synchronized Lists **before** accessed by multiple threads, like this:

```
for (String key : keys) {
    map.put(key, Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()));
}
```

**Or** you do it just in time like this:

```
List<Integer> list = map.get(key);
if (list == null) {
    map.putIfAbsent(key, Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()));
    list = map.get(key);
}
```

That's it. Now everything should be thread-safe.

**Note:** it is important to work with a list not before fetching it from the map. Due to concurrency more than one thread may try to add a missing list to the map, but only one of them will succeed. Hence after trying to add a missing list always fetch it afterwards from the map.

Comment: What happens if you don't know what the keys are beforehand?

Comment: You may use `map.putIfAbsent()` as well, skipping the initialization phase. But you have to do this every time before accessing the  value. But you may optimize around by try to get and only if get fails, `putIfAbsent()`.

Comment: I added sample code for the alternative you mentioned, not knowing the keys in advance.

Comment: @Harmlezz As you wrote in your last answer, a `list.add(value)` should be done outside the `if` statement, isn't true?

Comment: @Fab I do not know what you mean. `list.add()` may be safely done after all the code I posted. You may add something after you obtained the list which is stored in the map, not before. The double fetching of list is important in case some other thread added a missing list before.

Comment: @Harmlezz In a your previous answer there was a `list.add(value)` call after all the code. Maybe you deleted it accidentally. I asked you for this as a confirm that such a call should be performed after the code to add the new value to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the other answer will do what you want because you need to read from the map (to see if the key is already there or not) and then update in an atomic operation.

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but you could use something like this...

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

```
public class KeyLockMap<K, V> {

    private Map<K, V> map;

    private Set<K> lockKeys;

    public KeyLockMap() {
        map = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>();
        lockKeys = new HashSet<K>();
    }

    public void lock(K key) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(lockKeys) {
            // Keep waiting while the lockKeys set contains the key we want to update
            while(lockKeys.contains(key)) {
                lockKeys.wait();
            }
        }
    }

    public void unlock(K key) {
        synchronized(lockKeys) {
            lockKeys.remove(key);
            // Notify any threads that may be waiting for this key to be removed
            lockKeys.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public Map<K, V> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
}
```

Now in your threads, you can do...

```
keyLockMap.lock(KEY);
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = keyLockMap.getMap();
...do updates...
keyLockMap.unlock(KEY);
```

Hope this helps.

---

Another way that may work is to use "putIfAbsent" on a ConcurrentHashMap, for example...

```
List<Integer> newValue = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
List<Integer> value = concurrentMap.putIfAbsent(KEY, newValue);

if(value == null) {
    value = newValue;
}

value.add(DATA);
```

If another thread does the `putIfAbsent` first, you will get the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` that was created by that thread and you will be able to add data to it because the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is thread safe.

(Edited to account for null being returned on the first put...)

Comment: If using java 8, you might be able to just use a `ConcurrentHashMap` and `putIfAbsent` and then use CopyOnWrite lists as the value...

Comment: Please, could explain me better the CopyOnWrite step?

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap introduced in Java 7

Comment: @Panner actually in Java 5 :)

Comment: @BretC `value = concurrentMap.putIfAbsent(KEY, value);` returns `null` after the  new key has been created. So the next `value.add(DATA)` maybe will fail.

Comment: @Fab if `null` is returned, just add the data to the map you created

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel, `java.util.concurrent` package already contains thread-safe implementation of `Map` interface -  [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

However, you will have to synchronize your List as well (see BretC's comment below). So probably the most convenient solution would be to use [Guava synchronized multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#synchronizedMultimap(com.google.common.collect.Multimap)). Like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Multimap <String, Integer> map = Multimaps.synchronizedMultimap(HashMultimap.<String, Integer> create());

    // In Thread 1
    map.put("foo", 1);

    //In Thread 2
    map.put("foo", 2);

    System.out.println(map); // prints {foo=[1, 2]}
}
```

Comment: What happens if Thread 1 reads the map to see if the key exists (and it does not) and then Thread 2 reads the map to see if the same key exists (and it still doesn't)... Wouldn't one thread's put overwrite the other?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Hashtable instead of Hashmap. Hashtable is thread safe (already synchronized), not need implement again the lock/unlock mechanism.

Comment: So, could I pass the same (shared) data structure to both threads so that each of them can store its own part of data?